# Multiple Select and Copy on different pages

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with one sheet (Oz) updated daily.
The other sheet (Schedule) displays horizontally by week.
I identify the date of next Monday
search for that column in 'Schedule' and clear everything on 'Schedule' to the right of that column (This works with the clearschedule function).
Then I want to rebuild 'Schedule' with the latest data in 'Oz'
I sort 'Oz' on column K (This works). Then I filter for all the installs that  are in week 1 (start greater than or equal to next Monday and less than next Sunday). I copy the selection (H2:N?) from 'Oz', find the matching startWeek column on 'Schedule' and then paste the selected 'Oz'columns into 'Schedule'......week 1 plotted (This works)
Now I am trying to loop this 4 times (7 to 28 step 7) to select and copy from 'Oz' to the next 4 weeks in 'Schedule'. This is where the problem is.......It keeps pasting the original week 1 data into the next weeks on 'Schedule'

Can anyone tell me why the code doesn't filter, copy and paste the next week?

```
Sub tracker2()
  clearSchedule
  Dim fundingDate As Range
  Dim SourceLastRow As Long
  Dim sourceBook As Workbook
  Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
  Dim copyRange As Range
  Dim sched As Worksheet
  Dim startWeek As Date
  Dim endWeek As Date
  Dim f As Range
  Dim Col_letter
  Dim x As Integer
  Set sourceBook = ThisWorkbook
  Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets("Oz")
    'Determine last row of source from Oz
   With sourceSheet
       SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).row
   End With
   Columns("A:AM").Sort key1:=Range("K:K"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
   Set sched = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule")

   Set fundingDate = sourceSheet.Range("K1:K" & SourceLastRow)
   'need to loop 4 times
    For x = 7 To 28 Step 7
        startWeek = Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 1) + x
        endWeek = Date + (7 - Weekday(Date, vbMonday)) + x
        Set f = sched.Cells.Find(startWeek)
        Col_letter = Split(Cells(1, f.Column).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        'sets oz to sort on inst start
        With fundingDate
          .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
            ">=" & startWeek, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & endWeek
           Set copyRange = sourceSheet.Range("H2:N" & SourceLastRow)
           copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy sched.Range(Col_letter & "17")
       End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next x
  'close 4 times loop
  Cells.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you confused?  What happens when you run your code?

Comment: It copies the first selection, pastes the first selection on the first pass but then only pastes the first selection again again and again. The filter doesn't reset to the new selection for the second week, third etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the actual working code

```
Sub tracker3()
 clearSchedule
 Dim fundingDate As Range
 Dim SourceLastRow As Long
 Dim sourceBook As Workbook
 Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
 Dim copyRange As Range
 Dim sched As Worksheet
 Dim startWeek As Date
 Dim endWeek As Date
 Dim f As Range
 Dim x As Integer
 Set sourceBook = ThisWorkbook
 Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets("Oz")
'Determine last row of source from Oz which is the source worksheet
With sourceSheet
    SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).row
End With
'sorts sourcesheet based on Install Start
sourceSheet.Columns("A:AM").Sort key1:=Range("K:K"), _
                 order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Set sched = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule")

'need to loop 4 times for 4 weeks info
 For x = 7 To 28 Step 7
    Set fundingDate = sourceSheet.Range("K1:K" & SourceLastRow) 'install start
    Set copyRange = sourceSheet.Range("H2:N" & SourceLastRow) 'the 7 columsn to be copied
     startWeek = Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 1) + x
     endWeek = Date + (7 - Weekday(Date, vbMonday)) + x

     'With the source sheet Oz
     With sourceSheet
        Cells.AutoFilter '<<<remove any previous filter
        Cells.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=">=" & startWeek, _
                    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & endWeek
     End With

     Set f = sched.Cells.Find(startWeek) 'find the proper place to paste
     copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                           sched.Cells(17, f.Column)

 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Next x 'close 4 times loop

Cells.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try removing the filter before re-applying it within the loop?
Untested:

```
Sub tracker2()
    clearSchedule
    Dim fundingDate As Range
    Dim SourceLastRow As Long
    Dim sourceBook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim sched As Worksheet
    Dim startWeek As Date
    Dim endWeek As Date
    Dim f As Range
    Dim x As Integer

    Set sourceBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets("Oz")
    'Determine last row of source from Oz
    With sourceSheet
        SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    sourceSheet.Columns("A:AM").Sort key1:=Range("K:K"), _
                     order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    Set sched = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule")

    Set fundingDate = sourceSheet.Range("K1:K" & SourceLastRow)
    Set copyRange = sourceSheet.Range("H2:N" & SourceLastRow)

    'need to loop 4 times
     For x = 7 To 28 Step 7

         startWeek = Date - (Weekday(Date, vbMonday) - 1) + x
         endWeek = Date + (7 - Weekday(Date, vbMonday)) + x

         'sets oz to sort on inst start
         With fundingDate
            .Parent.Cells.AutoFilter '<<<remove any previous filter
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & startWeek, _
                        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & endWeek
         End With

         Set f = sched.Cells.Find(startWeek)
         copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                               sched.Cells(17, f.Column)

     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     Next x 'close 4 times loop

    Cells.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: Not quite.. It runs through the first time...the second time there is no filter and it fails in the with: "autofilter method of Range class failed" .

Comment: on the second pass..            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & startWeek, _
                        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & endWeek  ..............with the message "autofilter method of Range class failed"